# Exporting a DevExpress XtraReport to Text page by page

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I would like to be able to export only the first page of an XtraReport to text. I can see how to do it when exporting to HTML (or various other formats) using the exportoptions. I can't see any way to do it when exporting to text though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from DevExpress:

> Thank you for contacting us. To accomplish this task, you can use the
>   Page Merging technique. Refer to the [How to: Merge Pages of Two
>   Reports](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/CustomDocument3321) article for additional information. See the code below:

[VB.NET]

```
Dim report As New XtraReport1()
report.CreateDocument()

Dim ps As New PrintingSystem()
ps.Pages.Add(report.Pages(0))
ps.ExportToText(file)
```

It worked perfectly.